# PSCP Transfer File From Windows to Windows OS

Tags: copy, backup, transfer, pscp

i have 2 Server with different Segmentation Server (Windows OS) .
i need to backup the file weekly with simple copy/transfer file like this :

```
pscp -P 22 -pw password root@192.168.29.10:backup.zip C:\FolderBackup
```

This script works perfectly and copy to "C:\FolderBackup", but how can I specify the "backup.zip" in other drive folder like this "D:\BackupData\backup.zip"?